# Retrieve translated taxonomy term in current language programatically

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, i18n-l10n

How do I retrieve a specified taxonomy term translated (if translation exists for this term) from the current language context programmatically with D8?

Comment: [Here's how to do it with Drupal 7.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/79037/27135)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$curr_langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(\Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();

// retrieve term
$taxonomy_term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid);

// retrieve the translated taxonomy term in specified language ($curr_langcode) with fallback to default language if translation not exists
$taxonomy_term_trans = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($taxonomy_term, $curr_langcode);

// get the value of the field "myfield"
$myfield_translated = $taxonomy_term_trans->myfield->value;
```

Answer (score 10):

You should (must) use service instead at the first line for language_manager. Also I would shorten the code by using use tags.

Somewhere in the beginning of file:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
```

and later in the code in some function

```
$curr_langcode = \Drupal::service('language_manager')->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();
// Retrieve term.
$taxonomy_term = Term::load($tid);
// Retrieve the translated taxonomy term in specified language
// ($curr_langcode) with fallback to default language if translation not
// exists.
$taxonomy_term_trans = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($taxonomy_term, $curr_langcode);
// Get the value of the field "myfield".
$myfield_translated = $taxonomy_term_trans->myfield->value;
```

Answer (score 5):

The snippets above will return untranslated terms also. You must check if a term is translated with the hasTranslation function:

```
$vocabulary = 'MY_VOCABULARY_NAME';
$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
$query->condition('vid', $vocabulary);
$query->sort('weight');
$tids = $query->execute();
$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
$termList = array();

foreach($terms as $term) {
    if($term->hasTranslation($language)){
        $translated_term = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($term, $language);
        $tid = $term->id();
        $termList[$tid] = $translated_term->getName();
    }
}

// To print a list of translated terms. 
foreach($termList as $tid => $name) {
 print $name;
}
```

To link the tags to their term page: See: [Get taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144147/get-taxonomy-terms/243160#243160)

Answer (score 2):

An approach in preprocess node (handles multiple term references):

```
function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $node = $variables['node'];
  $langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $pathAliasManager = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager');

  if ($node->hasField("field_name") && !$node->get("field_name")->isEmpty()) {

    $terms = $node->get("field_name")->referencedEntities();

    foreach ($terms as $term) {

      $name = $term->name->value;
      if ($term->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
        $name = $term->getTranslation($langcode)->name->value;
      }

      $variables['termValues'][] = [
        'pathAlias' => $pathAliasManager->getAliasByPath('/taxonomy/term/' . $term->id()),
        'name' => $name,
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Then in Twig:

```
{% for items in termValues %}
  <a href="{{ items.pathAlias }}">
    {{ items.name }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```