# get taxonomy terms of specified language

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I know I can get list of of taxonomy of a vocabulary with

```
 $terms =  \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('course_category');

 kint($terms);
```

but it returned all that vocabulary terms, I am working on multi language site,**I want retrieve terms of specified language.**

*my Drupal version is 8.1.3*

Comment: did u pass vid of a particular vocabulary term u wanted to retrieve ??

Comment: yes ,but it return all of terms,`     $terms =  \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('course_category');
` . I just limit to specified language

Comment: Are you using any module for translation??

Comment: @ShreyaShetty drupal8 build-in support multi language.

Comment: Do you care about the tree structure provided by the loadTree method, or do you just want to load all the terms of said language?

Comment: @Eyal I have flat terms structure (one level). So I only want terms of specified language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the loadByProperties method to load all the entities that their fields correspond to certain values.

For a more advance selection you can use the entity query service.

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties([
  'vid' => $vid,
  'langcode' => $language_id
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulties with printing tags in the current language in code too. This is what worked to get ONLY the translated terms of a vocabulary:

```
$vocabulary = 'MY_VOCABULARY_NAME';
$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
$query->condition('vid', $vocabulary);
$query->sort('weight');
$tids = $query->execute();
$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
$termList = array();

foreach($terms as $term) {
    if($term->hasTranslation($language)){
        $tid = $term->id();
        $translated_term = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($term, $language);
        $termList[$tid] = $translated_term->getName();
    }
}

// To print a list of translated terms. 
foreach($termList as $tid => $name) {
     print $name;
}
```

To link the tags, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/243160/71941

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Stef Van Looveren's answer, but instead of loading all the taxonomy term IDs and then checking if each one has a specific translation, I include the language condition in the query.

```php
$vocabulary = 'MY_VOCABULARY_NAME';
$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$tids = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('vid', $vocabulary)
  ->condition('langcode', $language)
  ->sort('weight')
  ->execute();
$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
$termList = [];

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $tid = $term->id();
  $translated_term = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($term, $language);
  $termList[$tid] = $translated_term->getName();
}
```

This would return any term that has the `$language` translation, while `loadByProperties()` only returns the entity if the original language is `$language`.